# Does AndroidX still allow RelativeLayout?

Tags: layout, androidx

I searched for this string and got zero hits

*"androidx" -android RelativeLayout*

But I searched for *"androidx" -android*

and got plenty.  Kind of looks like they killed it.

Anybody know of a workaround?

Comment: Have you added the recyclerview dependency implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0' in you build.gradle(app) file?

Comment: I'll try it - thanks

Comment: I guess that isn't it.  It still says
error: package R does not exist RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) instance.findViewById(R.id.RelBox);